# Unable to locate package aclocal although automake is installed

Tags: apt, compiling

I am using Oracle VM VitualBox 5..(Ubuntu14.04 LTS on host OS window10) and wanted to compile [this](http://sympler.org/) software. I first installed automake and then try to install aclocal but its says E: Unable to locate Package aclocal (i also used update command). I browsed many websites but didn't find the solution. Automake is installed and at package.ubuntu.com i got answer, your search gave no results. I am a total beginner, will appreciate quick reply.

Comment: what software you were trying to install?

Comment: I am trying to install Sympler, a particle simulation tool. from website www.sympler.org. I am still trying to install it. Now i am getting warning, autoconf input should be named configure.ac, not configure.in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program `aclocal` is part of the `automake` package. You don't need to install it separately.

Comment: Thank you, The read me file with this software says that you need following tools   autotools (aclocal, libtool, autoconf, automake, etc.) which confused me.